# Server-side query using events or/and context?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I’m coding a bot using PHP-BotMan for complexity reasons and using Dialogflow query API to extract and manipulate the information from the response. I saw examples and hints from people here and on dialogflow forum suggesting using context or events, some of them mixing both. What is the better way to handle this?

The flow of the application is:

1. user messages bot
2. bot queries (text or/and #event?) dialogflow
3. internally process a reply or return dialogflow slotfilling* request
4. text response bot reply user with last reply or asking to fill slot

Also, how can I be sure that a slotfilling process is finished with “actionIncomplete” only having two values, NULL or TRUE? The dialogflow query response doesn't show which slotfilling parameters are required or not…

Thanks for the help!

- ***slotfilling*** is when dialogflow sends a text response requesting required parameters to finish an intent, adding those replied values to the context

Answer (score 0):

I was trying something similar to your scenario, here are few points i found helpful:

- When Slotfitting with webhook, i can't use the "Required" params field since i have to control the input parameters via webhook (query database to provide options). Which means actionIncomplete field is not useful anymore.
- I personally prefer to use context as it can add/remove params which gives you more control.
- Hence the dialog was designed to use webhook to check all required params before move on to next conversation flow. and pop quick replies menu to ease and restrict possible input from users.
  HTH.